# Looking for smart ways to make this Bootstrap/jQuery code "DRY"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to reduce this code a little. As usual with jQuery and Bootstrap it is fairly verbose. I would like learn how I can make it more DRY and through the use of what I think will be some combination of arguments and variables the art of re-useable code.

**NOTE:** These are effectively the same the only real difference is the "content". I will need to make the content and the "placement" unique per instance.

---

**Instance A**

```
    $('#popover-2').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement:'right',
        container:'body',
        content:'<h2>EPS Trailing 12 Months</h2><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus #2</p>'
    }).click(function(e) {
        $(this).popover('show');
        $('.popover-content').prepend('<a class="close">&times;</a>');
        $('.close').click(function(e){
            $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover('hide');
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

**Instance B**

```
    $('#popover-3').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement:'right',
        container:'body',
        content:'<h2>EPS Trailing 12 Months</h2><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus #2</p>'
    }).click(function(e) {
        $(this).popover('show');
        $('.popover-content').prepend('<a class="close">&times;</a>');
        $('.close').click(function(e){
            $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover('hide');
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cfs I think this is a valuable question with a great answer. I didn't know codereview.stackexchange.com/ existed. Is it new? Can this question be moved/migrated over there to benefit the community? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object where you store all the common options, like so:

```
var commonOptions = {
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement:'right',
    container:'body'
}
```

and the click callback in a named function:

```
var myClickCallback = function(e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
    $('.popover-content').prepend('<a class="close">&times;</a>');
    $('.close').click(function(e){
        $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover('hide');
    });

    e.preventDefault();
};
```

so your code will be:

```
var commonOptions = {
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement:'right',
    container:'body'
}

var myClickCallback = function(e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
    $('.popover-content').prepend('<a class="close">&times;</a>');
    $('.close').click(function(e){
        $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover('hide');
    });

    e.preventDefault();
}

$('#popover-2').popover($.extend({}, commonOptions, {
    content:'<h2>EPS Trailing 12 Months</h2><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus #2</p>'
})).click(myClickCallback);


$('#popover-3').popover($.extend({}, commonOptions, {
    content:'<h2>EPS Trailing 12 Months</h2><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus #2</p>'
})).click(myClickCallback);
```

Comment: I gotta admit at first this answer seemed the more elegant choice to me but it seems overly complicated unless the content is different, which in the example snippet it is the same and could be passed as a second argument to the helper function in my answer anyways

Comment: The content is the same because I was too lazy to change it :)

Comment: @patrick Perfect. Exactly the clean code and explanation I was after. I had to make a small tweak to make the code function (added var myClickCallback = ) in. Edited code above.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to wrap the event handling in a function, passing in the elements and options you want. Since we only need content and placement, we can pass those in separately. If we wanted to let the caller define all of the properties we would want to pass in an object literal instead of having a function with 5+ parameters.

```
var attachHandlers = function(element, content_, placement_) {                       
    element.popover({                                                                
        html: true,                                                                  
        trigger: 'manual',                                                           
        placement: placement_,                                                       
        container: element,                                                          
        content: content_                                                            
    }).click(function(e) {                                                           
        $(this).popover('show');                                                     
        $(this).find('.popover-content').prepend('<a class="close">&times;</a>');    
        $('.close').click((function(elem) {                                          
            return function() { $(elem).popover('hide'); };                          
        })(this));                                                                   
        e.preventDefault();                                                          
    });                                                                              
};                                                                                   

var content2 = '<h2>EPS Trailing 12 Months</h2><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus ' +         
    'vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus #2</p>';                                      
var content3 = '<h2>EPS Trailing 12 Months</h2><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus ' +         
    'vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus #3</p>';                                      

$(document).ready(function() {                                                       
    attachHandlers($('#popover-2'), content2, 'right');                              
    attachHandlers($('#popover-3'), content3, 'bottom');                             
});
```

There's a bug when the x is prepended to all elements with the popover-content class since you will end up prepending an x to all popover's not simply the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function popoverHelper(id){
    var element = $('#' + id);

    element.popover({
            html: true,
            trigger: 'manual',
            placement:'right',
            container:'body',
            content:'<h2>EPS Trailing 12 Months</h2><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus #2</p>'
        }).click(function(e) {
            $(this).popover('show');
            $('.popover-content').prepend('<a class="close">&times;</a>');
            $('.close').click(function(e){
                $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover('hide');
            });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```